# Can't read lines from file by using StreamReader on Unity3d (Android)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, filestream, streamreader

I need to read a text stream by using StreamReader from file on android platform. File is about 100k lines, so even editor is getting stuck if i try to load it all to TextAsset or if i use WWW.

I simply need to read that file line by line without loading it all to a string. Then i'll do a tree generation from the lines that i got from the file. (But probably that part doesn't matter, i just need help on file reading part.)

I'm giving the code that i wrote down below. It works perfectly on editor, but fails on android.

I would be glad if anyone tell me, what am i missing.

(ps. english is not my native and this is my first question on the site. so sorry for the any mistakes that i may have done.)

```
private bool Load(string fileName)
     {
         try
         {
             string line;
             string path = Application.streamingAssetsPath +"/";

             StreamReader theReader = new StreamReader(path + fileName +".txt", Encoding.UTF8);

             using (theReader)
             {


                 {
                     line = theReader.ReadLine();

                     linesRead++;
                     if (line != null)
                     {
                         tree.AddWord(line);

                     }
                 }
                 while (line != null);


                 theReader.Close();
                 return true;
             }
         }

         catch (IOException e)
         {
             Debug.Log("{0}\n" + e.Message);
             exception =   e.Message;
             return false;
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Application.streamingAssetsPath as a path on Android because streaming assets are stored within the JAR file with the application.

From http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html:

> Note that on Android, the files are contained within a compressed .jar
>   file (which is essentially the same format as standard zip-compressed
>   files). This means that if you do not use Unity’s WWW class to
>   retrieve the file then you will need to use additional software to see
>   inside the .jar archive and obtain the file.

Use WWW like this in a coroutine:

```
 WWW data = new WWW(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + fileName);
 yield return data;
 if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.error))
 {
    content = data.text;
 }
```

Or, if you really want to keep it simple (and your file is only a few 100k, stick it in a resource folder:

```
TextAsset txt = (TextAsset)Resources.Load(fileName, typeof(TextAsset));
string content = txt.text;
```

Comment: I've tried the methods you said earlier.

For instance when I tried to load it from resources and split it as follows:

`TextAsset txt = (TextAsset)Resources.Load (filename, typeof(TextAsset));

string[] linesInFile = txt.text.Split ("\n"[0]);  

  foreach (string line2 in linesInFile) {
   linesRead++;
   tree.AddWord(line2);

  }`

It works with test file which consists of 10 lines of words.
But the unity3d editor freezes when i try to run it with original file.
As I mentioned file is about 100k lines (near to 1mb)
So what am I missing exactly or what can I try other than this.

Comment: Ahh, right 100K lines. Yes, I have seen that the Unity editor will freeze/pause on any large text resource. I believe the work-around is to not name it FILE.TXT call it FILE.DAT.